# Самопроизвольное удаление БД. postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, ktor

Запускаю приложение kton на удаленной vps через docker. Предварительно создал БД, наполнил данными. Все работает, но через несколько часов приложение начинает отдавать 500. Захожу, смотрю базы данных нет. Почему она может самопроизвольно удаляться?

```
version: '2.24.5'

services:
  app:
    container_name: quote
    image: dmitriy/quote
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - quote-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=false
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=quote
volumes:
```

Comment: Потому что кто-то к ней подключился и удалил её, например. А вообще лучше всего посмотреть, что происходит, в логах.

Comment: Хм.. логи я смотрел, там огромная простыня, в котором я ничего подозрительного не увидел. Но гляну ещё раз.